# Drop Shadow effect on Windows SDK 10240

Tags: c#, uwp, composition, win2d

I know there are a lot of ways of adding shadows with the Anniversary Update and previous SDKs with Windows.Composition. Unfortunately I have to stick with version 10240 and this APIs are not available. I tried with Win2D but did not succeed. Any ideas on how to add a shadow to a Grid XAML element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you can't make a real drop shadow without the anniversary update in xaml (without using specific shadow bitmaps that you'd need to create yourself).

In case you only need a shadow to *rectangular* xaml components, you can make a 3x3 grid with gradients along the edges, and place it under the component with a certain offset (depending on where you want the light to come from).

Here is an example of that:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="YourProject.UserControls.CustomShadow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:YourProject.UserControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ShadowGrid" Opacity="0.2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftColumn" Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CenterColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightColumn" Width="40" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="TopRow" Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="CenterRow" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="BottomRow" Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0.5" EndPoint="1,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4b4b50" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4b4b50" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0.5" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4b4b50" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4b4b50" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Rectangle Fill="#4b4b50"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4b4b50" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0.5" EndPoint="1,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4b4b50" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4b4b50" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0.5" EndPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#4b4b50" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Width="350" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

When resizing the object, adjust the width/height of CenterColumn/CenterRow, and keep the other parts of the grid the same size. A radial gradient would've looked better in the corners, but radial gradients don't exist in uwp either.

Comment: Hi, I guess this  is the only way. Hoped something could've been done with Win2D but thanks for the answer!